# Разделы инфоблока отображают карту сата

Tags: битрикс

Добры день.
Создал раздел, в меню к нему выводятся дочерними пунктами разделы инфоблока. В каждом из разделов инфоблока есть элементы. Но почему то при переходе на раздел инфорбока отображается только карта сайта.
Для наглядности вот сайт: http://oknave5o.beget.tech
В верхнем меню пункт "Пластиковые окна" - раздел.
К нему выпадающие пункты - разделы инфобока, и при переходе например в "Окна для квартиры" видимо только карту сайта, а не список элементов этого раздела инфоблока.

Comment: `/plastic-windows/dlya-kvartiry/` выдает 404, поэтому и выводится карта сайта. Видимо неправильно настроены ЧПУ для разделов

Comment: @DmitryKozlov а подкажите, где из нудно настроить, никак не найду

Comment: так откуда ж мне знать, как у вас работает сайт. Это может быть в настройках инфоблока (если каталог на основе инфоблоков), может быть в "настройка обработки адресов" если это какие-то специфичные адреса, может это у вас реально существующие каталоги, но в них нет index.php. В общем масса вариантов